# How can i check if an attribute is set (not null and not an empty string) with jstl?

Tags: jstl

E.g.

```
<c:if test="${post}">
    <h3>${post.title}</h3>  
</c:if>
```

Comment: although if `title` does not exist (ie. the property does not belong to this variable/bean), you want to catch the `javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException` , see question `Checking attribute exists in JSP` on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2522562/checking-attribute-exists-in-jsp

Comment: Your question should probably be reformulated as "check if an attribute is **set**" (not null and not an empty string)

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Use the empty keyword

```
<c:if test="${not empty post}">
   <h3>${post.title}</h3>   
</c:if>
```

Comment: This is definitely the best way. I believe it also checks for `null`.

Comment: This is misleading. If the attribute is a list, it is set and is empty, this conditional would return true.

Answer (score 12):

You can also use '!' instead 'not'  :

```
<c:if test="${!empty post}">
    <h3>${post.title}</h3>
</c:if>
```