# Evaluate empty or null JSTL c tags

Tags: string, jsp, jstl, el

How can I validate if a `String` is null or empty using the `c` tags of `JSTL`?

I have a variable named `var1` and I can display it, but I want to add a comparator to validate it.

```
<c:out value="${var1}" />
```

I want to validate when it is null or empty (my values are string type).

Answer (score 829, accepted):

> *How can I validate if a String is null or empty using the c tags of JSTL?*

You can use the `empty` keyword in a [`<c:if>`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/tags/3.0/tagdocs/c/if.html) for this:

```xml
<c:if test="${empty var1}">
    var1 is empty or null.
</c:if>
<c:if test="${not empty var1}">
    var1 is NOT empty or null.
</c:if>
```

Or the [`<c:choose>`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/tags/3.0/tagdocs/c/choose.html):

```xml
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${empty var1}">
        var1 is empty or null.
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        var1 is NOT empty or null.
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Or if you don't need to conditionally render a bunch of tags and thus you could only check it inside a tag attribute, then you can use the EL conditional operator `${condition? valueIfTrue : valueIfFalse}`:

```xml
<c:out value="${empty var1 ? 'var1 is empty or null' : 'var1 is NOT empty or null'}" />
```

To learn more about those `${}` things (the [Expression Language](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info), which is a separate subject from [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info)), [check here](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/expression-language/5.0/jakarta-expression-language-spec-5.0.html).

#### See also:

- [How does EL empty operator work in JSF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14185031/how-does-el-empty-operator-work-in-jsf/)

Comment: For people who are having odd problems with the empty check, here's a fishy story with a possible cause: http://gayleforce.wordpress.com/2008/01/26/jstl-empty-operator/

Comment: Summarized: `empty` doesn't work on `Set` when using the ancient JSTL 1.0. You'd need to upgrade to JSTL 1.1 (which is from 2003 already).

Comment: @BalusC - Does the EL `${not empty var1}` check for both empty and null simultaneously? I mean the test is evaluated to true if and only if `var1` is **not** null **and** `var1` is **not** empty. Is there no need to check for `null` separately?

Comment: @BalusC - Thank you. I had already checked what you mentioned in your answer prior to my comment though I just wanted to clarify once, since a `null` value and an empty string are treated differently at many places (almost everywhere).

Comment: is `empty` equvilant to   ne ' '

Comment: @shareef: no, it isn't. In case of `String` values, it's equivalent to `var ne null and var ne ''`. Further it also supports `Object`, array, `Collection` and `Map`.

Comment: @BalusC `empty var1` was extremely useful instead of boolean Java.

Comment: @BalusC If this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/28360770/1097600 is copy pasted in the edit,  please give proper attribution. Thanks. You will always be our hero.

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but what if ... c:choose was replaced with c:if, taking the test from the c:when tag, and the c:when became c:then (without the 'test') and the c:otherwise became c:else? We would then have an if-then-else construct.

Answer (score 28):

to also check blank string, I suggest following

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

<c:if test="${empty fn:trim(var1)}">

</c:if>
```

It also handles nulls

Answer (score 8):

if you check only null or empty then you can use the  with default option for this: 
`<c:out default="var1 is empty or null."  value="${var1}"/>`

Answer (score 6):

This code is correct but if you entered a lot of space ('     ') instead of null or empty string
<c:if test="${empty var1}"> return false.

To correct this use regular expresion (this code below check if the variable is null or empty or blank the same as org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.isNotBlank) :

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>
<c:if test="${not empty description}">
    <c:set var="description" value="${fn:replace(description, ' ', '')}" />
    <c:if test="${not empty description}">
        The description is not blank.
    </c:if>
</c:if>
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's the one liner.

#### Ternary operator inside EL

```
${empty value?'value is empty or null':'value is NOT empty or null'}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `${var == null}` alternatively.

Comment: No, unfortunately, you can't. "" without any symbols in it is an empty string but is not null.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how to validate an `int` and a `String` that you pass from the Java Controller to the JSP file.

MainController.java:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/ImportJavaToJSP")
public ModelAndView getImportJavaToJSP() {
    ModelAndView model2= new ModelAndView("importJavaToJSPExamples");

    int someNumberValue=6;
    String someStringValue="abcdefg";
    //model2.addObject("someNumber", someNumberValue);
    model2.addObject("someString", someStringValue);

    return model2;
}
```

importJavaToJSPExamples.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

<p>${someNumber}</p>

<c:if test="${not empty someNumber}">
    <p>someNumber is Not Empty</p>
</c:if>

<c:if test="${empty someNumber}">
    <p>someNumber is Empty</p>
</c:if>

<p>${someString}</p>

<c:if test="${not empty someString}">
    <p>someString is Not Empty</p>
</c:if>

<c:if test="${empty someString}">
    <p>someString is Empty</p>
</c:if>
```

Comment: What's the issue with my comment?

Answer (score -1):

```
In this step I have Set the variable first:

<c:set var="structureId" value="<%=article.getStructureId()%>" scope="request"></c:set>

In this step I have checked the variable empty or not:

 <c:if test="${not empty structureId }">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);">Change Design</a>
 </c:if>
```