# JSTL and Scriplet

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

Can you tell me what's wrong in this code?
I'm using Spring MVC to send data. The scriplet is working but the jstl throws some error though both scriplet and jstl performs same action.

```
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@page import="biz.canisrigel.scg.common.RssParser.Item"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Twitter</title>
    </head>
<body>
    <%
        ArrayList<Item> feeds = (ArrayList<Item>) request
            .getAttribute("feeds");
        for (Item tfeed : feeds) {
            out.println(tfeed.description);
        }
    %>
    <c:forEach var="tfeed" items="${feeds}">
        <c:out value="${tfeed.description}" />
    </c:forEach>
</body>
</html>
```

Can you point where am I going wrong? Error thrown is **javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: An error occurred while evaluating custom action attribute "value" with value "${tfeed.description}": Unable to find a value for "description" in object of class "biz.canisrigel.scg.common.RssParser$Item" using operator "." (null)**

Added c:if as per Ravi's suggestion. Following is the error:

**An error occurred while evaluating custom action attribute "test" with value "${not empty tfeed.description}": Unable to find a value for "description" in object of class "biz.canisrigel.scg.common.RssParser$Item" using operator "." (null)**

Comment: I think description value is null in tfeed

Comment: @RaviG thats what I mentioned. Scriplet is fine and gives output. If I comment scriplet and run the jstl part error is thrown.

Comment: I think you have to use c:if to check if tfeed.description is null. See this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811626/evaluate-empty-or-null-jstl-c-tags

Comment: @RaviG check the added data to the question. I added c:if

Comment: Change this line to <c:out value="${tfeed.Description}" /> (change D into upper case.). Some explanation is given here - http://www.devrecipes.com/2009/09/30/jstl-errorunable-to-find-a-value-for-property-in-object-of-class-using-operator/

Comment: might be worth looking at your getters and setters in your tFeed bean

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking to your code, It seems the Item class does not have the getter method for the property 'description'. Please add it and verify it again It should work. Make sure the getter method is available when ever you access any property through EL.