# JSTL / EL equivalent of testing for null and list size?

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, jstl, el

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Evaluate empty or null JSTL c tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811626/evaluate-empty-or-null-jstl-c-tags)

I'm refactoring scriptlets to JSTL and EL and I would like to know how to write the following in JSTL / EL:

```
if(sokandeList != null && sokandeList.size() > 0) { %>
...
```

I don't know how to test for null and AFAIK EL can only access getters in this context so I must add a method getSize() to the sokandeList class. Correct? What should the JSTL / EL expression look like? Thanks for any help

Comment: I don't know if I understood your question but you need a backing bean with `getters` and, in your jsf page, you can write `#{backingBean.sokandeList ne null and sokandeList.size() > 0}`

Comment: Duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2811626/1285418).

Comment: Thanks for the help. Yes, it is sort of a duplicate but in this case BalusC was so ahead that he knew it's used in a for loop that already takes care of empty lists.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use the `empty` keyword, it checks both nullness and emptiness.

```html
<c:if test="${not empty sokandeList}">
    ...
</c:if>
```

Note that when your intent is to iterate over the list using `<c:forEach>` then it may be good to know that it already won't run when the provided `items` is `empty`. If the `<c:forEach>` is directly surrounded by this check, then this check is entirely superfluous.

#### See also:

- [Java EE 6 tutorial - operators in EL](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaik.html)
- [Java EE 6 tutorial - examples of EL expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaim.html)

Comment: Does `empty` works with arrays or just Collections?

Comment: Objects, strings, arrays, collections, maps, everything. On objects it only checks if it's not null. On arrays it also checks `length` and on the remnant it also checks `isEmpty()`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! And yes, it is used in a for loop in this case so I can rationalize to just the for loop that will be a good solution.

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>
<c:if test="${fn:length(sokandeList) > 0}">
```

I think you can use this too:

```
<c:if test="${!empty myObject.sokandeList}">
```

[Awesome JSTL cheat sheet](http://ndpsoftware.com/JSPXMLCheatSheet.html)

Comment: Thank you karim. But BalusC helped me even more telling me that I don't even need this test when what I'm doing is a `c:foreach` since that expression already contains this test.