# JSP Core tag failing when using equalsIgnoreCase inside scriptlet

Tags: java, jstl, jsp-tags

This could be something obvious but I can't figure it out.

Why does

```
<c:if test="<%= (aString!= null) && (!aString.equalsIgnoreCase(""))%>">
```

fail all the time while

```
<c:if test="<%=(aString!= null) && (aString.trim().length() > 0)%>">
```

work perfectly fine?
The scriptlets work perfectly fine outside the c:if so I am wondering what is wrong when I put it inside the core tag.
The exception goes like

> JSPG0055E: Unable to create an xml attribute from name [] value [))%]
>   Error Code: 500

Comment: I don't even understand what you're doing; a string scriptlet inside a JSTL test? You can't just randomly mix and match whatever you want (and even if you could, you shouldn't). What do you think belongs inside the `test` attribute?

Comment: Got it Dave. Upvoted. The fact of the matter is I am seeing so much of this kind of code that I am starting to write similar code.I have changed the implementation to <c:if test="${not empty aString and aString ne ''}">.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The particular error is caused by those doublequotes. They end the value of the `test` attribute too soon.

However, all with all this is not the right approach. In fact, you're doing it wrong by mixing "oldschool" *scriptlets* with "modern" taglibs. This syntax is not supported at all. You cannot use *scriptlets* in taglib attributes. You should be using EL — those `${}` things — in taglib attributes instead.

Provided that `aString` is been placed as an attribute of the page, request, session or application scope beforehand something like as

```
request.setAttribute("aString", aString);
```

then this should do in order to check if `aString` is not null nor empty:

```html
<c:if test="${not empty aString}">
```

#### See also:

- [Our EL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info)
- [Our JSTL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info)
- [How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files/3180202#3180202)
- [Evaluate empty or null JSTL c tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811626/evaluate-empty-or-null-jstl-c-tags/2811676#2811676)

Comment: Got it. Thanks. I have changed the implementation to <c:if test="${not empty aString and aString ne ''}">

Comment: You do not need to explicitly test for an empty string. The `empty` keyword already covers that. So just `${not empty aString}`, exactly as shown in my answer, is really all you need.

Answer (score -4):

You can't use equalsIgnoreCase on null and not set object. Why would you check string for not being null using equalsIgnoreCase, it's not good method. Your first check (=! null) is enough.

Comment: The check guarantees that if the object is null then `equalsIgnoreCase()` will never be called.  But that also doesn't explain or answer the crux of the problem.

Comment: @VahidFarahmand Because your answer is completely unrelated to both the actual problem (JSP syntax) and the next problem (a scriptlet inside something expecting an EL expression).