# How does EL empty operator work in JSF?

Tags: jsf, el

In JSF an component can be rendered or not using the EL empty operator

```
rendered="#{not empty myBean.myList}"
```

As I've understood the operator works both as null-check, but also check checks if the list is empty.

I want to do empty checks on some objects of my own custom class, which interface(s) or parts of interfaces do I need to implement?
Which interface is the empty operator compatible with?

Answer (score 161, accepted):

From [EL 5.0 specification](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/expression-language/5.0/jakarta-expression-language-spec-5.0.html#empty-operator-empty-a):

> ### 1.11 Empty Operator - `empty A`
>
> The `empty` operator is a prefix operator that can be used to determine if a value is
> null or empty.
>
> To evaluate `empty A`
>
> - If `A` is `null`, return `true`
> - Otherwise, if `A` is the empty string, then return `true`
> - Otherwise, if `A` is an empty array, then return `true`
> - Otherwise, if `A` is an empty `Map`, return `true`
> - Otherwise, if `A` is an empty `Collection`, return `true`
> - Otherwise return `false`

So, considering the interfaces, it works on [`Collection`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html) and [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html) only. In your case, I think `Collection` is the best option. Or, if it's a Javabean-like object, then `Map`. Either way, under the covers, the [`isEmpty()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#isEmpty()) method is used for the actual check. On interface methods which you can't or don't want to implement, you could throw `UnsupportedOperationException`.

Comment: Weird, I try to use this on a Long and eclipse (4.4.0) hints that "This empty expression always evaluates to false.  Only string, maps, arrays and collection have meaningful values 
 for the empty operator"

Comment: Even more weird, it always evaluates to true in my case.

Comment: What about if `myBean` is `null`? Will `true`/`false` still be returned or can it throw an exception?

Answer (score 9):

Using BalusC's suggestion of implementing Collection i can now hide my primefaces `p:dataTable` using not empty operator on my `dataModel` that extends `javax.faces.model.ListDataModel`

Code sample:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import javax.faces.model.ListDataModel;
import org.primefaces.model.SelectableDataModel;

public class EntityDataModel extends ListDataModel<Entity> implements
        Collection<Entity>, SelectableDataModel<Entity>, Serializable {

    public EntityDataModel(List<Entity> data) { super(data); }

    @Override
    public Entity getRowData(String rowKey) {
        // In a real app, a more efficient way like a query by rowKey should be
        // implemented to deal with huge data
        List<Entity> entitys = (List<Entity>) getWrappedData();
        for (Entity entity : entitys) {
            if (Integer.toString(entity.getId()).equals(rowKey)) return entity;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getRowKey(Entity entity) {
        return entity.getId();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        List<Entity> entity = (List<Entity>) getWrappedData();
        return (entity == null) || entity.isEmpty();
    }
    // ... other not implemented methods of Collection...
}
```