# Skip validation on a component when an Ajax request is triggered by that component

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I have a `p:autoComplete` component where I want to show links based on the selected item. A visual example:

> [image]

To do so, I update a component when the value of the `p:autoComplete` changes. Part of this is having a `p:ajax` listener on the `clear` event. This works great as long as the auto complete component is **not** required. When it **is** required, I run into a required validator message which is displayed.

So, I'm trying to skip validation when a request is triggered by the `clear` event. Inspired by [JSF skip Required-Validation without immediate=true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14335610/jsf-skip-required-validation-without-immediate-true), I've tried:

```html
<p:autoComplete required="#{param['javax.faces.source'] ne component.clientId and ...}"
                ...>
  <p:ajax event="clear" update="..."/>
</p:autoComplete>
```

and:

```html
<p:autoComplete required="#{empty param['primefaces.resetvalues'] and ...}"
                ...>
  <p:ajax event="clear" update="..." resetValues="true"/>
</p:autoComplete>
```

but both are not working. Is what I want at all possible? Please note that the component is used as a custom tag, so I cannot hardcode the full clientId.

I'm using JSF 2.3 (bundled with a recent Payara 5).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ajax event type is passed as request parameter with name of [`javax.faces.behavior.event`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/9/apidocs/jakarta/faces/component/behavior/ClientBehaviorContext.html#BEHAVIOR_EVENT_PARAM_NAME).

So this should do:

```xml
<p:autoComplete required="#{param['javax.faces.behavior.event'] ne 'clear'}">
```

It's wise to doublecheck if this is invoked on the very component itself else it'll also be skipped when the very ajax event happens to be fired by another component:

```xml
<p:autoComplete required="#{not (
    param['javax.faces.source'] eq component.clientId 
        and 
    param['javax.faces.behavior.event'] eq 'clear'
)}">
```

Comment: But then the `param['javax.faces.source'] ne component.clientId` I've tried should have worked, right? That check should pass any Ajax request by the component, not just `clear`.

Comment: Hmm, works for me. Perhaps `#{component}` is in your context not the one you expected it is?

Comment: I was able to prefix the auto complete label with `#{component.clientId}`, so the implicit object works as expected. Going to accept your answer as it works for you. Will fix my issue with a workaround.