# Can we assign "empty" value using c:set?

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

I need to assign object value as empty. I know we can use

```
<c:set var="xyz" value=""/>
```

But can we assign like below snippet?

```
<c:set var="xyz" value="${empty}"/>
Its giving me **Unable to parse EL function ${empty}.**
```

Comment: If you already have a simple solution that works, why would you try for a complex solution that doesn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`empty` is an operator, not a value. You should use `${null}`.

See also:

- [How does EL empty operator work in JSF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14185031/how-does-el-empty-operator-work-in-jsf) (don't mind the JSF part, the EL part is valid for JSP).