# Primefaces selectonemenu on string check null value

Tags: jsf, primefaces, render, selectonemenu

I want to render a panelgroup only if the value of my selectOneMenu is not null.
I have this:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.myString}">
    <f:selectItem itemValue=#{null} itemLabel="None" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="first" itemLabel="First" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="second" itemLabel="Second" />
    <f:ajax render="panelWrap" />
</h:selectOneMenu>

<h:panelGroup id="panelWrap">
    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{bean.myString == null ? false : true}">
        // My content
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:panelGroup>
```

I did this a lot with objects but here I am stuck on a simple string value.
Can anybody help?
Thanks

Comment: Apart from the XML syntax error and the clumsy double boolean condition, I don't see any problems. What exactly is it, the problem you're having with it? What exactly do you mean with "a simple string value"? Do you want to check if `"first"` is selected or so? If so, why did you ask that you want to check for `null`?

Comment: You forgot the double quotes `"` at `#{null}`.

Comment: I mean that the condition in the 'renderer' doesn't work properly. The panel group is always hidden even when I select 'First' or 'Second'. I would like to make it hidden only when I select 'None'.

Comment: Also, what BalusC meant by the double boolean condition is you don't need to explicitly check if you condition evaluates to true or not. Example: `rendered = "#{bean.myCondtion == true}"` not necessary, you can simply do `rendered = "#{bean.myCondtion}"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your first `<f:selectItem>` change `itemValue=#{null}` to `itemValue="#{null}"`. In your second `panelGroup` change the rendered condition to `"#{not empty bean.myString}"`. You might find this link helpful.

[Evaluate empty or null JSTL c tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811626/evaluate-empty-or-null-jstl-c-tags)