# JSP EL: Why does the not operator evaluates to true on undeclared variable

Tags: java, jsp

I have the following piece of code that evaluates to true:

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${not isAddressNotFound}">
            <%-- Always evaluates to true -->
    </c:when>
</c:choose>
```

However, the `isAddressNotFound` variable is never defined in the code.

Is this a feature at the time of evaluating a variable that has been never defined instead of throwing an error? If so, what would be the benefits of doing so?

Comment: EL is smart enough to avoid such `NullPointerException`. Try `Value:"${isAddressNotFound}"` that prints `Value:""` it means if variable is found/declared then it convert it to empty string. If you are looking for solution then try with `${not empty isAddressNotFound}` that checks for `null` as well as emptyness.

Comment: Try `${isAddressNotFound != null}` check. Read more [Evaluate empty or null JSTL c tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811626/evaluate-empty-or-null-jstl-c-tags)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a better approach for testing whether or not one variable is defined is the tag

```
<%@taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-logic" prefix="logic"%>
```

That you can use with

```
<logic:present name="isAddressNotFound">
    User object exists.
</logic:present>
```

or

```
<logic:notPresent name="isAddressNotFound">
    User object does not exists.
</logic:notPresent>
```

In order to fully accomplish your goals.