# HTTP Status 500 - Exception occuring at string to int conversion

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jsp, amazon-rds

Environment : I am working in eclipse kepler, my MySQL database is on AWS RDS. My aim is to create a web based project hence my project is of "AWS Java Web Project". Also for database connectivity i have already added the mysql-connector-*-bin.jar file to my build path.

The below code when i run as a simple java application, it runs fine, but when i run it on Tomcat server it shows me the following errors :

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /WelcomeCustomer.jsp at line 114

line 114 :

```
     String s_id_string=(String)request.getParameter("s_id");       
    int s_id = Integer.parseInt(s_id_string);
```

root cause

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
org.apache.jsp.WelcomeCustomer_jsp._jspService(WelcomeCustomer_jsp.java:180)
```

line 180 :

```
o_insert.setString(4, Cust_contact_string);
```

Note: Cust_contact_string is of type string.

Please help me i cnt seem to get through this error!

Thanks in advance

updating  :

```
<form name="s_id_form" method="post" onsubmit=" return s_id_form()"> 
Choose a Shop from above by entering the respective s_id : 
<input type="text" name="s_id" id="s_id"> <input type="submit" value="submit"> 
</form>     
<%  
String s_id_string=(String)request.getParameter("s_id");    
int s_id = Integer.parseInt(s_id_string);   
%>
```

Comment: for more reference i am pasting the entire code :

Comment: You cannot parse null into a number. So be sure whether null or not before conversion (parsing).

Comment: yes i am checking that it is not null through a javascript code as below : function s_id_form()
            {
                var s_id = document.s_id_form.s_id;
                if(s_id.value == "")
                {
                window.alert("Enter the Shop ID!");
                return false;
                }
                return true;
            }

Comment: Don't post code as comment, instead updated your post with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because `s_id_string` is `null`.Modify your code as,

```
String s_id_string=(String)request.getParameter("s_id");       
int s_id=0;
if(s_id_string !=null || s_id_string !=""){
  s_id = Integer.parseInt(s_id_string);
}
else{
  s_id=0;//assign any value
}
```

Comment: thanks it worked.., sorry i do not have enough reputation as yet to upvote u.., will definitly do so in time.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Do not trust client side validations. Always put server side validations as well.

The exception is obvious to the input provided(`null`).

Please check for `null` before proceeding. As well as check for `""`.

And after the checks provided wrap your code in `try catch block` to do something when weird input passed to the server side.

Answer (score 0):

> An exception occurred processing JSP page `/WelcomeCustomer.jsp`

I suggest you to avoid Scriplet and use [JSP Standard Tag Library](https://jstl.java.net/) and [Expression language](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) to avoid such errors.

```
${param.s_id}
```

---

Read more about [JSP - Implicit Objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnahq.html#bnaij)

> `param:` Maps a request parameter name to a single value
>
> ---

You can use the [`<c:if>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/if.html) or [`<c:choose>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/choose.html) for this to check for `null` and `empty` values.

```
<c:if test="${empty param.s_id}">
    s_id is empty or null.
</c:if>
<c:if test="${not empty var1}">
    s_id is NOT empty or null.
</c:if>
```

or

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${empty param.s_id}">
        s_id is empty or null.
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        s_id is NOT empty or null.
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

The `${not empty param.s_id}` can also be done by `${!empty param.s_id}`.

[Learn more...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811626/evaluate-empty-or-null-jstl-c-tags)