# Errors in JSP with missing variables on tomcat 7

Tags: spring, jsp, jstl, tomcat7, sap-commerce-cloud

I have a Spring installation that was running fine on tomcat 6 however in attempting to update to tomcat 7 I get a lot of errors in my JSP files. Most notable is that if a variable doesn't exist it doesn't just evaluate as null as it used to, it errors out. is there a configuration value for this? or some way to test if the variable exists? every-time I ask for a nonexistent variable even just to test if its empty or null it throws an error...

i.e.

```
${not empty cmsPage.label} //throws an error if cmsPage.label doesn't exist. This used to resolve as false if it didn't exist...
```

EDIT:

it seems that the root cause is a javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException, which makes sense. I guess what is confusing me is why this just started when I updated. Our JSP pages used to never care whether a property existed or not. We have a lot of old code that uses null checks to check for properties hopefully I don't have go through all of it to catch PropertyNotFoundExceptions. Maybe there is a config value I can use to ignore these? or if needed what would be the best way to check if a property exists?

Here is the stack trace:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/views/desktop/pages/category/smithCategoryListingPage.jsp at line 17

14: <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn"%>
15: 
16: 
17: ${not empty cmsPage.label}
18: <template:smithopticspage pageTitle="${pageTitle}">
19: 
20:     <style>


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:470)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1180)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:950)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:256)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$StatisticsGatewayFilter.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:345)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:226)
    com.so.storefront.filters.btg.BTGSegmentFilter.doFilterInternal(BTGSegmentFilter.java:47)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:226)
    com.so.storefront.filters.btg.AbstractBtgFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractBtgFilter.java:57)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:226)
    com.so.storefront.filters.btg.AbstractBtgFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractBtgFilter.java:57)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:226)
    com.so.storefront.filters.btg.AbstractBtgFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractBtgFilter.java:57)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:226)
    com.so.storefront.filters.btg.AbstractBtgFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractBtgFilter.java:57)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:226)
    com.so.storefront.filters.CrossScriptingFilter.doFilterInternal(CrossScriptingFilter.java:43)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:226)
    com.so.storefront.filters.SpecialAccountsFilter.doFilterInternal(SpecialAccountsFilter.java:478)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:226)
    com.so.storefront.filters.CustomerLocationRestorationFilter.doFilterInternal(CustomerLocationRestorationFilter.java:63)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:226)
    com.so.storefront.filters.CartRestorationFilter.doFilterInternal(CartRestorationFilter.java:133)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:226)
    com.so.storefront.filters.AnonymousCheckoutFilter.doFilterInternal(AnonymousCheckoutFilter.java:62)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:226)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:139)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter.doFilter(ChannelProcessingFilter.java:144)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:226)
    com.so.storefront.filters.UrlEncoderFilter.doFilterInternal(UrlEncoderFilter.java:100)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:226)
    com.so.storefront.filters.StorefrontFilter.doFilterInternal(StorefrontFilter.java:73)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:226)
    com.so.storefront.filters.cms.CMSSiteFilter.doFilterInternal(CMSSiteFilter.java:108)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:226)
    com.so.storefront.filters.RequestLoggerFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestLoggerFilter.java:79)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:226)
    com.so.storefront.filters.AcceleratorAddOnFilter.doFilter(AcceleratorAddOnFilter.java:92)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:226)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.SessionFilter.doFilter(SessionFilter.java:73)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:226)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain.doFilterInternal(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:156)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    com.so.storefront.filters.UrlPathFilter.doFilterInternal(UrlPathFilter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:256)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$StatisticsGatewayFilter.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:345)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:226)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.RedirectWhenSystemIsNotInitializedFilter.doFilter(RedirectWhenSystemIsNotInitializedFilter.java:104)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:226)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.TenantActivationFilter.doFilter(TenantActivationFilter.java:91)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:226)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.Log4JFilter.doFilter(Log4JFilter.java:47)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:226)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain.doFilterInternal(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:156)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    com.so.storefront.filters.AcceleratorAddOnFilter.doFilter(AcceleratorAddOnFilter.java:92)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
root cause

javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'label' not found on type de.hybris.platform.cms2.model.pages.CategoryPageModel
    javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.get(BeanELResolver.java:266)
    javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.access$300(BeanELResolver.java:243)
    javax.el.BeanELResolver.property(BeanELResolver.java:353)
    javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:97)
    org.apache.jasper.el.JasperELResolver.getValue(JasperELResolver.java:104)
    org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:183)
    org.apache.el.parser.AstEmpty.getValue(AstEmpty.java:46)
    org.apache.el.parser.AstNot.getValue(AstNot.java:43)
    org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:184)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:967)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.desktop.pages.category.smithCategoryListingPage_jsp._jspService(smithCategoryListingPage_jsp.java:145)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1180)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:950)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:256)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$StatisticsGatewayFilter.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:345)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:226)
    com.so.storefront.filters.btg.BTGSegmentFilter.doFilterInternal(BTGSegmentFilter.java:47)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:226)
    com.so.storefront.filters.btg.AbstractBtgFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractBtgFilter.java:57)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:226)
    com.so.storefront.filters.btg.AbstractBtgFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractBtgFilter.java:57)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:226)
    com.so.storefront.filters.btg.AbstractBtgFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractBtgFilter.java:57)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:226)
    com.so.storefront.filters.btg.AbstractBtgFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractBtgFilter.java:57)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:226)
    com.so.storefront.filters.CrossScriptingFilter.doFilterInternal(CrossScriptingFilter.java:43)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:226)
    com.so.storefront.filters.SpecialAccountsFilter.doFilterInternal(SpecialAccountsFilter.java:478)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:226)
    com.so.storefront.filters.CustomerLocationRestorationFilter.doFilterInternal(CustomerLocationRestorationFilter.java:63)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:226)
    com.so.storefront.filters.CartRestorationFilter.doFilterInternal(CartRestorationFilter.java:133)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:226)
    com.so.storefront.filters.AnonymousCheckoutFilter.doFilterInternal(AnonymousCheckoutFilter.java:62)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:226)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:139)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter.doFilter(ChannelProcessingFilter.java:144)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:226)
    com.so.storefront.filters.UrlEncoderFilter.doFilterInternal(UrlEncoderFilter.java:100)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:226)
    com.so.storefront.filters.StorefrontFilter.doFilterInternal(StorefrontFilter.java:73)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:226)
    com.so.storefront.filters.cms.CMSSiteFilter.doFilterInternal(CMSSiteFilter.java:108)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:226)
    com.so.storefront.filters.RequestLoggerFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestLoggerFilter.java:79)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:226)
    com.so.storefront.filters.AcceleratorAddOnFilter.doFilter(AcceleratorAddOnFilter.java:92)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:226)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.SessionFilter.doFilter(SessionFilter.java:73)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:226)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain.doFilterInternal(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:156)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    com.so.storefront.filters.UrlPathFilter.doFilterInternal(UrlPathFilter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:256)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$StatisticsGatewayFilter.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:345)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:226)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.RedirectWhenSystemIsNotInitializedFilter.doFilter(RedirectWhenSystemIsNotInitializedFilter.java:104)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:226)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.TenantActivationFilter.doFilter(TenantActivationFilter.java:91)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:226)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.Log4JFilter.doFilter(Log4JFilter.java:47)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:226)
    de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain.doFilterInternal(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:156)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    com.so.storefront.filters.AcceleratorAddOnFilter.doFilter(AcceleratorAddOnFilter.java:92)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
```

Comment: you need to check condition in jstl if statment

Comment: It seems that someone adding new label attribute in cmsPage model and in you local, system is not updated. please do run update system and check.

Comment: Have you seen this : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811626/evaluate-empty-or-null-jstl-c-tags][1]

Comment: If `CategoryPageModel` is modified and your JSP/JSF now accesses fields that do not exist anymore, would that not lead to unexpected results by ignoring and just returning null or an empty string? To me it would even be better if this could be trapped during compile time rather than at runtime. Otherwise I could suggest to [write a custom `ELResolver`](http://memorynotfound.com/creating-custom-el-resolver-jsf/).

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you are trying to use the "label" attribute off the **de.hybris.platform.cms2.model.pages.CategoryPageModel**. There is no attribute 'label' on this type. This is only present for **de.hybris.platform.cms2.model.pages.ContentPageModel**.

"pageTitle" should be written by your controller already. you do not need to do that check.

Answer (score 0):

By the **propertyNotFoundException** the issue is often that you use the messageBean for localization in a jsp. So you have to set the property in your specific *.property file