# JSP not empty object

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

I have this object that is null, I checked in the controller; and in the jsp if I put this

```
*${deviceForm.device.secondSignatory}*
```

I see `**`

however in this check I see the alert !

```
<c:if test="${not empty deviceForm.device.secondSignatory}">
    <script>
    alert ('not empty-> ' + '${not empty deviceForm.device.secondSignatory}'+ '*${deviceForm.device.secondSignatory}*');

    </script>
</c:if>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Evaluate empty or null JSTL c tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811626/evaluate-empty-or-null-jstl-c-tags)

Comment: in JSTL, `null` is the same as empty.

Comment: Plase check my answerr @Amadeu Cabanilles