# How to check in JSTL whether object is javabean or Collection?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, jstl

I want to get the filled from an object; it may be a javabean or a collection.

I tried this:

```
 ${rolesInfo.name}
```

but it was wrong if the rolesInfo are an array,I have to write like this:

```
${rolesInfo[0].name}
```

I try to use `${rolesInfo[0]['class']}` to get the object type ,but it do not work in tomcat8.May be it only be used in tomcat 6.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Evaluate empty or null JSTL c tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811626/evaluate-empty-or-null-jstl-c-tags)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `${rolesInfo.getClass().simpleName}` in tomcat 8. I would like to emphasize on one more point that `${rolesInfo['class'].simpleName}` do not work too.