# How to check JSP variable and hide if value is null/empty or some specific string?

Tags: java, jsp

I am creating a project where i am getting set data in JSP page from database.
if any field data value is null the jsp page is showing null but i do not want to show it on jsp page. please help. i am getting data from bean.

```
<%=p.getOffer()%>
<% String s = p.getOffer() %>
<% if (<%=s ==null) { %> 
show nothing
```

Comment: Someone already answered a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811626/evaluate-empty-or-null-jstl-c-tags

Comment: Please accept the answer which helped you most in solving your problem. It helps future readers. If the answers weren't helpful leave comments below them. So the poster can update them accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

If you are coding java inside a jsp, you need to use scriptlet tags(`<%` and `%>`). So if you are checking for conditions you need to open a scriptlet tag.

```
<%    
    String s = p.getOffer();
    if (s != null && !s.equals("")) {
        out.print(s);
    } else { %>
<!-- s is either null or empty. Show nothing -->
<% }%>
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you want to show when the value is `null`? Anyway, your approach looks good:

```
<%=p.getOffer()%>               // Here you print the value "offer". If you don't want to show it when it is null, remove this line
<% String s = p.getOffer() %>   
<% if (<%=s ==null) { %>        // the <%= is unnecessary. if(s==null) is enough
show nothing                    // show nothing, why not inverse the if and show something
```

Here another approach:

```
 <%
    String s= p.getOffer();
    if(s != null){ %>
        Offer: <%= s%>
 <% }%>
```

That way you only print the offer when the variable is not null. 
By the way: naming a String variable "s" is not recommended, call it "offer" or something to facilitate the reading.

Comment: sorry, my JSP is a little rusty. I am not sure about the <% anymore. And I think to remember that there is an output writer you can use: `if  (s!=null) { out.println("Offer : "+s); }` Then you don't have to escape the java code all the time you want to print the content of a variable.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am putting offer text + html tags in offer variable if offer is nothing or null do't need  to show in jsp/html page.